# How to put file content to http request header by using Apache httpd

Tags: apache

I can send http request to /foo, add header plaa to request and finally redirect request to /bar with following Apache httpd configuration (foobar.conf file)...

```
<LocationMatch "/foo">

ProxyPass http://localhost/bar
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/bar
ProxyPassReverse https://localhost/bar

RequestHeader set plaa "hello"

</LocationMatch>
```

How can I put plaa header's value as base64 encoded file content?

I could image I could do it like this...

```
sed -i s_plaa_$(cat file.txt | base64)_g foobar.conf
```

but I'm wondering is there any built in way to do it with Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apache httpd do not support reading http header content from file.**

Here's quick fix for doing this manually in Unix environment.

(Following steps could be easily put to script file if you want to.)

Step 1.

```
    Go to 'location_where_apache_httpd_is_running:/etc/httpd/conf.d'
```

Step 2. Create file for header value.

```
    echo 'your base are belong to us' > header_value.txt
```

Step 3. Write following lines to file apache_app.conf_base.

```
    Listen 8001
    ProxyPass /foobar/ http://localhost:8002/foobar
    ProxyPassReverse /foobar/ http://localhost:8002/foobar
    Header add App-Header "value"
    RequestHeader App-Header "value"
```

Step 4. Replace 'value' strings with base64 encoded header_value.txt.

```
    sed s_value_$(echo $(cat message.json | tr -d "\n\r") | base64 -w 0)_g apache_app.conf_base > apache_app.conf
```

Step 5. Restart httpd

```
    service httpd restart
```

Now apache httpd do following things based on apache_app.conf.

1. Redirect requests from localhost:8001/foobar to localhost:8002/foobar
2. Attach header 'App-Header' with value as base64 encoded lines from file header_value.txt.